# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument

Tags: selenium

I am getting the following error after running the code:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'SADAF-RAUF', ip: '192.168.1.55', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [99bdbf5c25fd5790a4c9901c3f7f1dde, clickElement {id=1d9cbee0-b4cb-4993-b271-3a3e36c42165}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Sadaf\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64336}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:64336/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.114, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (99bdbf5c25fd5790a4c9901c3f7f1dde)] -> id: uploadPicture]
Session ID: 99bdbf5c25fd5790a4c9901c3f7f1dde
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:78)
at com.autoit.FileUpload.upload(FileUpload.java:25)
at com.autoit.FileUpload.main(FileUpload.java:32)[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMkb7.png)

Answer (score 0):

//use Sendkeys

driver.findElement(By.id("uploadPicture")).sendKeys("L:\Software\wrar511b1.exe");

Comment: Hi, this is uploading the exe file itself. I need to upload the image through the script. Please help.

Comment: @SadafRauf driver.findElement(By.id("uploadPicture")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Ranvijay\\Desktop\\image1.jpg");

Comment: Hi this is working correctly, but I am supposed to upload it using AutoIt. And also just wanted to know the root cause of this error.